# Switching to different font size(s) locally

Tags: fontsize

Inside a 12pt document I like to switch in an environment to a font size of 10pt. The macros like `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\small` etc. should all work like in a 10pt document. I'm aware that this isn't good typography and might look bad in general. I'm planning to use it for the labels inside a `tikzpicture`.

The task (I don't like to call it a "problem") is that I have some `standalone` `tikzpicture` documents which are using 10pt when compiled standalone, but can be also inserted into 12pt documents where the text does not fit any more in some places. I know it could be fixed by changing all distances to one of the font size specific units `em` or `ex`, but don't like to change several figures and maybe add this as a feature to the `standalone` package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\let\savednewcommand\newcommand
\let\newcommand\renewcommand
\makeatletter
\input{size10.clo}
\makeatother
\let\newcommand\savednewcommand
```

Or implement the contents of `size10.clo` yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting. I forgot that the font sizes are set by `.clo` files.

Comment: It was difficult to call which answer to accept. I was choosing this one because it's includes the full code required to change the font size at the begin of an environment.

Comment: Thanks again. This is now part of `standalone` v1.0 and is used to apply the used class font size option of subfiles even if they are included in a main document. See the `obeyclassoptions` option of the `standalone` package.

Comment: I tried applying this after a tikzpicture environment, and before some text. However, it changed the size of the text in the tikzpicture too.

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
abc {\large abc} 
{\makeatletter\let\newcommand\renewcommand\input{size12.clo}
abc \large abc} 
abc
\end{document}
```

But it won't work with every class/fontsize. E.g. with book you will have to input book12.clo, and the koma classes computes some fontsizes.

Comment: Thanks. The files in question will be `standalone` files, i.e. just single picture environments. The `article` class is used for that. The main document might be book or a koma class, but I like to actually switch to the "normal" 10pt style of the `article` class, so `size10.clo` should do it.

Comment: I can't find a `book12.clo` file but there is a `bk12.clo` file, which looks like it.

Comment: I am sorry, but is there a difference between your approach and this: `normal-font text {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont text to change its font locally} continue normal-font text`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou You are simply switching to 10pt, Martin wanted to redefine *all* size commands to give a bit smaller font.

Comment: I see. The question title confused me. Thanks for your explanation.