# Compile several files in their own font size in a main document

Tags: fontsize, subfiles

I use the `subfiles` package to compile several files in a main document.

I have for example a document `file1.tex` in 12 pt, and another `file2.tex` in 10 pt both in `article` class( in preamble : `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, and `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`).

I want to compile them in the file `main.tex` :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}

\makeatletter
\let\org@subfile\subfile
\renewcommand*{\subfile}[1]{%
    \filename@parse{#1}% LaTeX's file name parser
    \expandafter
    \graphicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\filename@area}}%
    \org@subfile{#1}%
    \newpage
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subfile{file1}
\subfile{file2}

\end{document}
```

But how to tell LaTeX to compile `file1.tex` in 12 pt and `file2.tex` in 10 pt ?
I'm searching a way to pass the fontsize of the files.tex files as an argument to the `main.tex` file, something which looks like `{\fontsize{"fontsizeoffile1.tex"}\selectfont\subfile{file1}}` maybe ?

I want to do this for many files, so the need to take automatically the font size in the file for each file.

Thank of help.

Comment: Related: [Switching to different font size(s) locally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15835). The solution there should probably work for your case.  Put the relevant `\input` commands in the subfiles.

Comment: you really want section headings to vary in font size as you move from section to section?

Comment: I was trying the solution with the related post [Switching to different font size(s) locally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15835), but it erased my setup marges (`geometry` package), and it's tedious to put in each file this code, more than put `[12pt]` in class option. But thanks for your answer.