# How to specify document font size less than 8pt?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I want to use the smallest readable font for cheatsheet, 
`\documentclass[6pt]{extarticle}`
doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It should be possible with `xelatex`, but who can read a 6pt font?

Comment: @Bernard I have Magnifying glass.

Comment: If you use magnifying glass, you don't want such a small size…

Comment: Your answer suggests a *local* change to the font size, and therefore points to the following *duplicate*: [Switching to different font size(s) locally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15835/5764)

Comment: @Werner , ok, I  didn't notice that before, since I wanted a global change

Comment: Another option is to use a normal font size on a large paper format.  Then shrink to fit a smaller paper format when printing.

Comment: Related question: [fontsize - Why do Latex classes often have font size limitations? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603096/why-do-latex-classes-often-have-font-size-limitations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to pick a font that supports arbitrary scaling, such as `lmodern`, and then use the `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont` approach to select it.  The revised font size will stay active until subsequently changed.

As to default size at startup, LaTeX only supports 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt, which is why the `[6pt]` option was ignored in the OP's approach.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{10pt}{11pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{8pt}{9pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{4pt}{5pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{3pt}{4pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\selectfont XYZxyz\par
\fontsize{1pt}{2pt}\selectfont XYZxyz
\end{document}
```

[image]

Eliminating the use of `lmodern`, one will find that the fontsize cannot be reduced below 5pt, since the default computer-modern font is not arbitrarily scalable.

[image]

p.s.  With `lmodern` selected, one should just as well add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble, to take advantage of the extra glyph set.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, I found the solution.

`\begin{document}
\tiny`