# Why do Latex classes often have font size limitations?

Tags: fontsize

I am a new user of Tex and am planning to just forget Latex and write raw Tex documents. One of the major reasons for this is that nearly all the common Latex classes I have seen have seemingly crazy text size limitations. If I use a an ordinary word processor I can use any font I want between 8 points and 48 points or even larger. However, if I use the "article" class (a common suggestion for writing letters), I only have a choice of [10, 11 or 12 pt.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381/the-article-class-ignores-14pt) Why is this?

Comment: Here are options: [How to get an even smaller font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57673/5764); [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5339/5764); [Need smaller than `\tiny`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50863/5764)

Comment: (La)TeX is designed to respect some common typographical rules... And these rules are about typesetting for print ready documents. You can use the package `anyfontsize` to adjust the sizes to your preferred amounts... But this is not suggested for example for a book that will be printed. You can do whatever you want in LaTeX but this is not word (fortunately) and you have to find the way to do it. LaTeX rules comes from old good typography and they respect that.

Comment: You can use a class like  scrartcl from the Koma bundle, it allows to set arbitrary font sizes.

Comment: Only 8 points or larger? With the `memoir` class you can use 23 font sizes from 4pt to 132pt and also the ability to define your own values.

Comment: Published books, reports, articles and other documents, are typically set in 10--12pt fonts. Newspaper headlines are a different matter. The LaTeX 10pt, 11pt and 12pt class options give font sizes ranging from 5pt to 30pt, sufficient for most typeset documents.

Comment: I might mention is passing that DVI browsers often have to precompute the fonts used as bit maps.

Comment: Download KOMA-script classes. Problem solved. (FYI a class is simply a package, with a slightly different purpose.)

Comment: I'm curious what use-case you have that can't be accommodated by those three styles together with the usual sizing in LaTeX (`Huge`, `huge`, `scriptsize`, etc.).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question shows a misunderstanding, you can have fonts any size you like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

{\fontsize{2pt}{3pt}\selectfont 1}
{\tiny 2}
3
{\Huge 4}
{\fontsize{4cm}{4cm}\selectfont 5}

\end{document}
```

the options that you mention are not font sizes or even lengths, they are option names that set a whole range of things, the default font size, the page size, vertical spaces used around display environments and lists etc.

The names are just vaguely reminiscent of lengths so you can remember what they do. the `10pt` and `12pt` options do, amongst other things, set the default font size to 10pt and 12pt respectively. The `11pt` option doesn't set anything to 11pt, it sets the default font size to 10.95pt for historical reasons, but the option name is just a name.

For the default Computer Modern font family the font sizes are restricted to a range of sizes (but not just 10,11,12pt, the actual list of allowed sizes is  5pt 6pt 7pt 8pt 9pt 10pt 12pt 10.95pt 14.4pt 17.28pt 20.74pt 24.88pt) but that restriction is just for historical compatibility and if you add the `fix-cm` package you can have Computer Modern at any size, just as you can other font families such as the latin modern I used above.

Comment: Well this business that an option name called `11pt` <-- note the "pt" - is "just a name" that is "vaguely reminiscent of lengths" is rather confusing to a newcomer, eh?  Can you point to _other_ option names in LaTeX that are similarly "just a name" that is similarly seemingly precise yet is only "vaguely reminiscent" of what the straightforward meaning would indicate to the new user?  'Cause I have the same misunderstanding as the OP and I bet I'm not the only one!

Comment: In fact, check out the [linked question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70381/the-article-class-ignores-14pt?noredirect=1&lq=1) - that poster had the same question after trying the obvious solution (`14pt`) - the answer with 53 checks said well, `article` supports only these sizes _without mentioning that the the names are only "vaguely reminiscent" of actual point sizes_ and provides an alternative - and then a comment points out that the alternative works for 14pt but not others like 15pt or 16pt!  Well, that explains everything!  It's totally clear now how you pick a font size!

Comment: @davidbak I was perhaps over stessing the point by saying `10pt` is "reminiscent", but in fact latex doesn't treat it as a length at all in the standard classes it is basically just used as an option name to load `size10.clo`, `size11.clo` or `size12.clo` if you look at those files you will see that setting `\normalsize` to 10pt or whatever is only a very minor part (1 line out of 250 or so lines)

Answer (score 8):

The historical reason is that Donald E. Knuth shipped TeX with a font family that that came in different versions, proportioned for each of those sizes.  Variable fonts and different optical sizes in the same font file would be decades in the future.

Also, the original LaTeX class option syntax doesn’t parse `10pt` or `12pt` as a number followed by a unit. There’s a small, finite set of size options, including `11pt`. People might want to display a very large font for a title or the first letter of a chapter, but that could be handled with something like `\fontsize`.  The standard LaTeX document  classes were intended for math papers that would be printed out on a laser printer, and no one would choose a main font whose size was either illegible or would waste that much toner. (Which could be more expensive than gold.) If you want more flexibility than that, you load a class or package with a `key=value` option syntax.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that 99% of my documents used a normal size of 10, 11 or 12pt. So the provided defaults simply cover the typically needed sizes.

It is not very difficult to create a 14pt or 20pt setup, not more difficult than setting up the font sizes for a plain TeX document.
You can check the values in one of the .clo files and adjust them to your needs. Or if you want it easy, you can use a package like `extsizes` or classes like memoir or the KOMA bundle which have built-in options for more sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome this limit by using the `fontsize` package (see the documentation for details). For example:

```
\usepackage[fontsize=13.3]{fontsize}
```

sets the normal size to 13.3pt and the line spacing to ~15.96pt.

The line spacing can also be declared explicitly (here is 14.5pt):

```
\usepackage{fontsize}
\changefontsize[14.5pt]{13.3pt}
```

You can see the values for all the available font sizing commands with the `\printsamples` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage{fontsize}

%\sampletext{Hello world}

\begin{document}

\printsamples{13.6pt}{12.3pt}

\end{document}
```